# Tridiagonal Solver in Python

Tags: python, linear-solver, scipy

I have a code I'm working on that involves solving a 1D Schrodinger equation using a Crank-Nicolson time step.  The code is written in NumPy/SciPy, and I was doing a bit of profiling and discovered that the bulk of the simulation time is taken up with calls to the linear solver (spsolve in this case).  I'm using a simple discretization such that my matrices are symmetric and tridiagonal, and I was wondering if anyone had tried doing things like implementing the Thomas algorithm directly and if this was able to beat spsolve.

Comment: Why don't you simply try scipy.linalg.solve_banded, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solve_banded.html.

Comment: ... or [`scipy.linalg.solveh_banded`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.solveh_banded.html) for banded Hermitian positive definite matrices